# POST an image to PHP using only the URL from Cordova app

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cordova

Given just the URL, or the FileEntry object.  How do I POST an image to a PHP script?  I have no form or DOM to draw on, just the URL to the image from FileEntry.nativeURL.
I tried following this but it seems to require the DOM.
[POST an image to PHP in AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36668551/post-an-image-to-php-in-ajax)
This script will run detached from any page, so it can't use anything from any specific page.

Thanks.

Comment: From what environment are you making the `POST` request? A server where you have access to the CLI?

Comment: Javascript Cordova, from a script that get's stored into localstorage, and ran when conditions are met, online, wifi, etc.  Because the script is stored and then retrieved, it loses all access to the DOM and can't be certain what page it's on.  However I am using jquerymobile, so I can append outside the data-role=page if needed, but I prefer not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, had to request the file from myself to convert it to a blob, then place it in a FormData object and post it.

```
imageData.image_path='file://etc'
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.responseType = "blob";
    oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
         var blob = oReq.response;
         var formData = new FormData();
         formData.append("image", blob);
         var sendImage = new XMLHttpRequest();
         sendImage.open("POST", "https://website/upload-handler");
         sendImage.onload = function (oEvent) {
             resolve(oEvent);
         };
         sendImage.onerror = function (e) {
             reject(e);
         };
         sendImage.send(formData);
    };
    oReq.onerror = function (e) {
        reject(e);
    };
    oReq.open("GET", imageData.image_path, true);
    oReq.send();
});
```

This is a snip of the solution.  The promise returned is used by my queuing system to keep retrying until successful.